# Can a HelixToolkit BillboardSingleImage3D have an alpha blended image?

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

OK, simple issue with BillboardSingleImage3D in HelixToolkit (SharpDX version). If I make a BillboardSingleImage3D with a BitmapSource, the alpha channel areas show up as black. If I use the same BitmapSource in a standard WPF Image the alpha channel works just fine.
[image]

The big red/blue circles are the same image as the small one. The big image is in a WPF Image control, and the smaller circles are in BillboardSingleImage3D in a Viewport3DX.

Simply put, can I get the alpha channel to work in a BillboardSingleImage3D?

Thanks

Garry

Comment: never worked with this toolkit but generally in wpf you might be able to use an opacity mask

Comment: There is a mask colour, so I can mask out black, but only black, i.e. not any translucent black like you like get in a drop shadow or something. Basically I'm looking to render PNGs with alpha blending as billboards and have them show up as they would in regular WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It supports alpha with PNG format.